# Let f(x) be the generating function of the series $a_n$ ، $n\geq0$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How can I express the generatiing function of $\frac{1}{n}a_n$, $n\geq1$?
I tried with integral but something went wrong with me.

Comment: Your $\LaTeX$ isn't working, looking at your original version, maybe you meant `\frac{1}{n} a_n` $\frac{1}{n} a_n$ or `\frac{a_n}{n}` $ \frac{a_n}{n} $?

Comment: Thanks,it is right now.

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be the generating function of $(1/n)a_n$, then differentiate.

Comment: Yes.I derived g(x) in order to get something including f(x). But I might not succeed.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is the generating function of $a_n$, and $g$ is the generating function of $\frac{a_n}{n}$. Then $$g’(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{a_n}{n}x^n)’ = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n x^{n-1}) = \frac{f(x) - a_0}{x}$$ Thus, by Newton-Leibniz formula $$g(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f(t)-a_0}{t}dt$$

Comment: Thnaks.I think that it would be $\frac{f(x)-a_0}{x}$ since f(x) also includes $a_0$.what do you think?

Comment: @user722601, yes, you are right.

Comment: With same f(x), how can I find the generating function of $\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}$

Comment: @user722601, $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^n a_n a_{n - k} x^n = (\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_nx^n)(\sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k x^k) = (f(x))^2$

Comment: Got it,and if $n\geq0$ in the external index, it would change aomething?

Comment: @user722601, what do you mean by "external index"?

Comment: The index n in the external sum

Comment: @user722601, no, in this case it would not change anything.